In a Quarkus multi-module project, where do I place the container-license-acceptance.txt?
Trying to set up a project following this basic layout:
https://github.com/marcelkliemannel/quarkus-frontend-example
I am trying to use quarkus 3.14, with mssql.  It attempts to download and run a mssql docker container, but errors out stating it needs the license acceptance file.  I have tried to place it at every level, but it does not appear to be locating it:
project/
  src/test/resources/container-license-acceptance.txt

  frontend/
    src/test/resources/container-license-acceptance.txt
  backend/
    src/test/resources/container-license-acceptance.txt
  distribution/
    src/test/resources/container-license-acceptance.txt


The error message was misleading.  Because I am running mvn quarkus:dev, the file needed to be at:
project/distribution/src/**main**/resources/container-licence-acceptance.txt
